# mysql pattern matching on first 5 characters in two different table then input data into seperate column

Tags: mysql, sql, string, join, sql-update

I suck at mysql commands, please help. Here is what the tables looks like.

```html
table1
StudentID AlternateName
15654654 William001
45245324 Smith002
45245245 Wilson003
23423232 Johnaton004
45345322 Robert005
88787164 Joshua006
45645442 Jessie007

table 2
RealName ZipCode AltName
Smith  66521 null
johnaton 55224 null
Robert  63118 null
william  53210 null
Jessie  88763 null
wilson  55754 null
Joshua  78301 null
```

I need to create a foreign key in table2 to link up to table1. I have similar data but not exact match. I need to take first 5 character of column AlternateName in table1. If first 5 characters match any first 5 characters of column RealName in table2 (**regardless of case***), then write the data from AlternataName into a column call AltName in table 2.

For example. William001 in table1 should match up to william in table2 and William001 will be written to AltName for that row. Yes my primary key is an name follow by a number. I know this is not what it should be, but it's what I need to do.

How can I do this using mysql? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on the 5 leftmost character of the names (case insensitively) and update the matching records.

Consider:

```
update table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 
    on lower(left(t1.AlternateName, 5)) = lower(left(t2.RealName, 5))
set t2.AltName = t1.AlternateName
```

Note: this strategy will probably not behave consistently if there are multiple matching records...

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need. I ran into a problem with the code on MySQL Workbench 8.017. It says: "lower" is not valid at this position, expecting a complete function call or other experssion.

Comment: @NickHer: possibly: `left(lower(t1.AlternateName), 5) = left(lower(t2.RealName), 5)`?

Comment: your first code works flawless. It was my mistake that generated that error. The actually tables I have are more complicated then what I shared in the example. I learned to trim down my column names. Thanks a million.